# One border by combining objects

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to combine two objects, so that only the outer border is displayed. Additionally, I want to reuse the second object several times. See here my example code:

```
\documentclass[class=tufte-book]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \newsavebox{\test}
        \savebox{\test}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[fill=PuBuGn-9-1] (-1, 0.0) -- (-1,-1) -- (1,-1) -- (1,0);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }

        \draw[fill=PuBuGn-9-1] (-1,-2) -- (3, -1) -- (4, 2) -- (2,3)  -- (-1,-2);
        \node[rotate=60] at (3,-0.5){\usebox{\test}};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result of this code is this picture (the border of both objects is the same, it looks different because of the jpeg compression):

[image: Not combined]

But I'd like to have this kind of result:

[image: Combined]

Is that possible? Because calculating the cross-section would be difficult...
Thank you very much.

Comment: Related question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200478/tracing-a-border-formed-by-circles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one idea (first draw then fill).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    path1/.style={
        insert path={(-1,-2) -- (3, -1) -- (4, 2) -- (2,3)  -- (-1,-2)}
    },
    path2/.style={
        insert path={(-1, 0.0) -- (-1,-1) -- (1,-1) -- (1,0)}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % first draw
        \begin{scope}[thick]
            \draw[path1];
            \draw[rotate=60, shift={(1,-2.4)}][path2];
        \end{scope}
        % then fill
        \begin{scope}[red!30]
            \fill[path1];
            \fill[rotate=60, shift={(1,-2.4)}][path2];
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]